# How to check if names stored as elements of an array exist as independent arrays themselves

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have the following arrays:

```
$table_names = array('foo', 'bar');
```

And I have some other arrays:

```
$foo = array('1', '2', '3');

$bar = array('4', '5', '6');
```

I want to check if the names stored in $table_names exist as independent arrays. For example:

```
foreach($table_names as $names) {

    // Check if array exists with name $names

}
```

Can anyone please tell me if it's possible?

I'm basically exporting my database in PHP array format. I upload the file using the script and then I want to use those arrays in my code so I can show particular information on screen without having to add data into database.

Thank you in advance!
Cheers

Comment: It is possible through variable variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is is possible through the use of [`variable variables`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
foreach($table_names as $n) {
    if(isset($$n) && is_array($$n)) {
        print_r($$n);
    }
}
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/173067)

---

Basically variable variables are used like this:

```
$VARIABLENAME
```

Since we loop through `$table_names` as a 1D array, you can check `$$n` to see if it exists and is an array, if so, `print_r()` it.

**Note:** The manual shows this warning:

> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's
>   Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable
>   $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced
>   dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_GLOBAL`, assuming they are global variables.

```
if (isset($_GLOBAL[$table_names[0]]) && is_array($_GLOBAL[$table_names[0]]))
    echo "yep, its an array\n";
```